# show output of loops in realtime

Tags: php, .htaccess, header

I have a php script which is something like below.

**script.php**

```
<?php
foreach($available as $loop)
{
echo file_get_contents($loop);
}
?>
```

basically loop runs like 100 to 200.When I run `domain.com/script.php` on browser..output is displayed only after all the loop is completed.But I want the page to update the output in realtime.

Is it posible by setting some kinda of header in php script or via htacces ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with *some* servers using the [`flush()` function](http://php.net/flush).

You may be better off using JavaScript and AJAX to fetch and display progress of your long-running task, though.

Comment: I cant use javascript..cos it involves database and stuffs..ill look through flush()